# Powershell Header Record

Tags: powershell

I have a scenario like below:
I have a `.dat` file where header field name which is coming as below example:

```
2_a 2_b 2_c 2_d 2_e - Header
a b c d e - Data
f g h I j - Trailer
```

Next time

```
1_a 1_b 1_c 1_d 1_e -Header
c d e f g -data
b d f j k - trailer
```

So I want to achieve like my header record number is dynamically changing. Is there any way that I can achieve it so that I will just put the value and it will pick that value before that...like if I will input value 3 the header record will become `3_a 3_b` like that....
After that my data will come and then trailer...Please suggest me the process as I am new to powershell...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a line like

> 2_a 2_b 2_c 2_d 2_e

or

> 1_a 1_b 1_c 1_d 1_e

dynamically, you could use the string format operator, -f, like this

```
$index = 2
$header = "{0}_a {0}_b {0}_c {0}_d {0}_e" -f $index
```

this will create the first header and save it to a variable. Change the `$index` variable to create another string with some other number instead.

See this [link](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) for more info on its usage.